# How to test if headers are added properly to HTTP request

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, junit5

I have a method like:

```
@Service
public class ProductFacadeImpl implements ProductFacade {

  private NutritionixHeader nutritionHeaderParam;
  private RestTemplate restTemplate;

  public ProductFacadeImpl(NutritionixHeader nutritionHeaderParam, RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    this.nutritionHeaderParam = nutritionHeaderParam;
    this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
  }

  public HttpEntity addUniversalHeaderForRequest() {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("x-app-id", nutritionHeaderParam.getNutritionixAppId());
    headers.set("x-app-key", nutritionHeaderParam.getNutritionixAppKey());

    return new HttpEntity(headers);
  }
}
```

I want to test if my method is adding properly headers to the HTTP request.

My test looks like:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.LENIENT)
class ProductFacadeImplTest {

  @Mock
  private NutritionixHeader nutritionixHeader;

  @Mock
  private RestTemplate restTemplate;

  @InjectMocks
  private ProductFacadeImpl productFacadeImpl;

  @Mock
  private UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder;

  @Mock
  private ResponseEntity responseEntity;

  @Mock
  private HttpHeaders httpHeaders;

  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() {
    productFacadeImpl = new ProductFacadeImpl(nutritionixHeader, restTemplate);
  }

  @Test
  void addUniversalHeaderForRequest() {
    //given
    given(nutritionixHeader.getNutritionixAppId()).willReturn("id");
    given(nutritionixHeader.getNutritionixAppKey()).willReturn("key");

    //when
    productFacadeImpl.addUniversalHeaderForRequest();

    ArgumentCaptor<HttpEntity> httpEntityCapture = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(HttpEntity.class);
    ArgumentCaptor<HttpHeaders> httpHeadersCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(HttpHeaders.class);

    verify(httpHeaders).set(eq("x-app-id"), eq("id"));
    verify(httpHeaders).set(eq("x-app-key"), eq("key"));

    HttpHeaders headers = httpEntityCapture.getValue().getHeaders();

    assertEquals("id",
        headers.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals("x-app-id"))
            .map(Entry::getValue)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(""));
  }
}
```

but when I start it I am receiving an information like:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
httpHeaders.set("x-app-id", "id");
-> at com.application.nutritionix.service.ProductFacadeImplTest.addUniversalHeaderForRequest(ProductFacadeImplTest.java:196)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

I know that I suppose to use `ArgumentCaptor` but I cannot determine how to use `httpEntityCapture`  properly to solve this example. 
Thanks for your suggestions on how to reach a goal.

Comment: If you are testing `addUniversalHeaderForRequest` and it is returning an object - why not make assertions on the returned object directly? `headers` is a local variable so it cannot be mocked.

Comment: @michalk I completely don't know why I was insisting on ArgumentMatcher. You have right.